# CSS order in Drupal 8 libraries.yml

Tags: theming, 8

From what I read about Drupal 8 themes there does not appear to be anything to order CSS file loading. As you know, CSS cascades down to a specific order when there is a conflict with an element. Since I have a class that is named the same as Twitter Bootstrap which is loaded from the CDN from the page.html.twig, I can usually modify a bootstrap class by having the CSS file that loads last as that can trump the bootstrap class that loads earlier. I have not discovered how to set an external library like Twitter Bootstrap in the libraries.yml file so it's in my page.html.twig file. So here is my THEME.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/reset.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      css/htme-elements.css: {}
      css/tabs.css: {}
      css/messages.css: {}
      css/block-editing.css: {}
      css/wireframes.css: {}
      bootstrap/bootstrap.css: {}
      bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      css/layout.css: {}
      css/default.css: {}
```

The default.css should load last which has the class I would like to override in bootstrap, but after

```
drush cache-rebuild
```

I find that the element is choosing the bootstrap element. OK, let me put the default.css element highest in the stacking order in case Drupal is putting in a different order. But after rebuilding my cache again, I find that bootstrap still "wins."

The closest thing in the Drupal docs was to perhaps add stylesheets-override in my THEME.info.yml

```
stylesheets-override:
  - system.theme.css
```

How should I set the order so that I can use the external Bootstrap files and load in my default.css last?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a separate library for external bootstrap stylesheet, which will give you flexibility to load bootstrap css before loading global-styling css. Here's how to do it:

**YOURTHEMENAME.info.yml**

```
# Defines libraries group in which we can add css/js.
libraries:
  - sp/bootstrap // ADDED - note: this should go before your global-styling
  - sp/global-styling
...
```

**YOURTHEMENAME.libraries.yml**

```
# note: bootstrap library should go before global-styling  
# use { type: external } for external resources
bootstrap:
      css:
        theme:
         '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css': { type: external }
global-styling:
      css:
    ...
```

Comment: I would also add that you can weight within defined libraries to ensure that the weighting is as desired. From https://drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets - **You have 5 different css levels of styling:** ```base key assigns a weight of CSS_BASE = -200
layout key assigns a weight of CSS_LAYOUT = -100
component key assigns a weight of CSS_COMPONENT = 0;
state key assigns a weight of CSS_STATE = 100
theme key assigns a weight of CSS_THEME = 200```

Comment: @DannyEnglander Good point. Though it is also good to mention that external libraries like bootstrap have css rules that will fall into every one of those levels of styling. A new library may be a better choice for someone who is really meticulous about keeping the structure of their CSS files according to SMACSS standards. Always good to have options.